# How can I run a windows batch internal command remotely?

Tags: windows, command-line, remote-desktop, batch

I have two Windows computers `A` and `B`, and I want to remotely run a command on computer `B`. I use the tool `psexec`, so on computer `A` I can run:

```
psexec.exe \\10.0.0.2 -u user -p pasword c:\programs\whatever\commando.exe
```

to execute the command on computer `B`. So fine so good.

But how to simply run `dir` on the remote computer, which is an internal batch command?

```
 psexec.exe \\10.0.0.2 -u user -p pasword dir
```

just gives

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this example:

```
psexec \\10.0.0.2 -u user -p pasword -s cmd /c dir c:\
```

The key is the `cmd /c` to access the cmd shell

Source: http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html

Comment: I see. Perfect, just what I was missing here. Thanks.